# C++ How to convert date from input (string year, string month, string day) to time_point

Tags: c++, time

My teacher said that i have to convert the file with lines like that:

```
Jan Kowalski 1997 4 3
```

to class person with pools like:

```
string name, surname;
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point dateofbirth;
```

How can i create time point from 3 integers? I suppose it is not the easiest way to store that kind of data.

> "A reference to a specific point in time, like one's birthday, today's dawn, or when the next train passes.
>   In this library, objects of the time_point class template express this by using a duration relative to an epoch (which is a fixed point in time common to all time_point objects using the same clock)."

But how do i make duration from those data?

I suppose i should start with something like:

```
using std::chrono::system_clock;
system_clock::time_point today = system_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<60 * 60 * 24> > one_day;
```

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe [from_time_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t) can be your friend?

Comment: A school teaching modern C++ for real? Wow!

Answer (score 5):

You can start by storing the birth date in std::tm (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm), a structure that holds a date and time broken down into its components. For example:

```
std::tm tm;
tm.tm_mday = 3;
tm.tm_mon = 4;
tm.tm_year = 1977;
```

This std::tm structure can be converted to std::time_t (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t), which holds the number of seconds since epoch.

```
std::time_t tt = timegm(&tm);
```

Which in turn can be used to create the std::chrono::system_clock::time_point you are looking for:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point dateofbirth = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(tt);
```

Comment: I did it this way: `std::tm timeinfo = std::tm();
 timeinfo.tm_year = rok - 1900;   // year since 1900 ex. 100 = 2000
 timeinfo.tm_mon = miesiac - 1;      // month: january
 timeinfo.tm_mday = dzien;     // day: 1st
 std::time_t tt = std::mktime(&timeinfo);
 ur = system_clock::from_time_t(tt);`

Answer (score 3):

Here are several low-level date algorithms which can be used to convert three integers into a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`:

> [`chrono`-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html)

You can view this paper as a cookbook for how to write the algorithms portion of a date class.

Here is an example date class based on these algorithms.  It contains a type-alias called `days` that is quite similar to your `one_day`.

> [`date`](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html)

Here is a time zone library built on top of `date` that includes a `parse` function that can be used to parse dates (and times) out of files:

> [Time Zone Database Parser](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html)

As this is homework, you may just want to stick with the underlying algorithms paper.

Comment: This is what i have done:                                          `std::tm timeinfo = std::tm();                         
 timeinfo.tm_year = rok - 1900;   // year since 1900 ex. 100 = 2000
 timeinfo.tm_mon = miesiac - 1;      // month: january
 timeinfo.tm_mday = dzien;     // day: 1st
 std::time_t tt = std::mktime(&timeinfo);
 ur = system_clock::from_time_t(tt);`

Answer (score 1):

// create tm with 1/1/2000:

std::tm timeinfo = std::tm();

timeinfo.tm_year = 100;   // year: 2000

timeinfo.tm_mon = 0;      // month: january

timeinfo.tm_mday = 1;     // day: 1st

std::time_t tt = std::mktime (&timeinfo);

system_clock::time_point tp = system_clock::from_time_t (tt);

Example is here to convert the std::tm to time_point:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)